# How to change tabbar icon color from default blue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have got four tabs. I was able to change the tab icon color from default blue to red (or probably any color) and it works perfectly fine. The  problem is it works only for three tabbaritems and last one is default blue. Below is the code. I'm coding this in `rootviewcontrollerAppDelegate.m` You could try this by pasting the below code in your appdelegate. Could you guys help me out I'd be so greatful!

```
@implementation UITabBar (ColorExtensions)

- (void)recolorItemsWithColor:(UIColor *)color shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset shadowBlur:(CGFloat)shadowBlur

{

CGColorRef cgColor = [color CGColor];

 CGColorRef cgShadowColor = [shadowColor CGColor];

for (UITabBarItem *item in [self items])

 if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedImage)] &&

    [item respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelectedImage:)] &&

       [item respondsToSelector:@selector(_updateView)])

{

CGRect contextRect;

  contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;

 contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;

 contextRect.size = [[item selectedImage] size];
            // Retrieve source image and begin image context

 UIImage *itemImage = [item image];

 CGSize itemImageSize = [itemImage size];

 CGPoint itemImagePosition; 

 itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);

  itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) / 2);

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);

  CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            // Setup shadow

  CGContextSetShadowWithColor(c, shadowOffset, shadowBlur, cgShadowColor);
            // Setup transparency layer and clip to mask

  CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);

 CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);

 CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, 

    itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [itemImage CGImage]);
            // Fill and end the transparency layer

 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, cgColor);

 contextRect.size.height = -contextRect.size.height;

    CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);

  CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(c);
            // Set selected image and end context

  [item setSelectedImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            // Update the view

 [item _updateView];

}

}
@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    

    [[tabBarController tabBar] recolorItemsWithColor:[UIColor redColor] shadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] shadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.0f) shadowBlur:3.0f];

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        [self addTabBarArrow];

         return YES;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no problem for self-add tabbar-item, i test this code for 4 items;

but your last tabbar item is a system tabbar item(the"....""more" item), so this code maybe has no use for it; its just not use image your set in;

Comment: thanks man...i ve stuck into another problem..this above code just worked for only one application..i tried dis same code in other application it din work...cud u try this stuff.probably..in some other application...and reply me

Answer (score 8):

```
 [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your sharing.

But there are some flaws where deploying on iPhone4 or iPod4 which have retina display.
The selected icon in the tarBar will be smaller than the unselected one.

So I would like to share my fix here:

```
CGSize orginalSize = [[item selectedImage] size];
double scaleFactor = 1;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
    contextRect.size = CGSizeMake(orginalSize.width*scaleFactor, orginalSize.height*scaleFactor);

// Retrieve source image and begin image context
UIImage *itemImage = [item image];
double imageScale = 1;
if ([itemImage respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    imageScale = itemImage.scale;
}
CGSize itemImageSize = CGSizeMake(itemImage.size.width*imageScale, itemImage.size.height*imageScale);
```

If I am wrong, please free fee to let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation MoreViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = @"More";
        self.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"]; // here more.png is Yellow Image
    }
    return self;
}

//.......
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your asset folder, find the asset and click on Identity Inspector , and change "Render As" to Original Image

[image]