# How do I change background color of UITabItem when item is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I would like a different background color when the user selects a tab bar item than when it is unselected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put this in the `Appdelegate.m` in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UIImage *whiteBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBackground"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:whiteBackground];
```

Answer (score 12):

if you use a storyboard or xibs, click "Tab Bar" and add "selectedImageTintColor" path into the Key Path Attributes tag. Like this :

[image]

Comment: Isn't it OP asking about changing background color ?

Comment: Yeah this changes the text color of the selected tab only.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: As of iOS 7.1 this technique no longer works (if the user taps the same tab twice in succession, the background colour is cleared).**

---

`UITabBarItem` is a subclass of `UIBarItem`, everything is more painful because UIBarItem doesn't subclass `UIView`; however, `UITabBarItem` *contains* one. What follows manipulates that view, and therefore might be rejected if submitted to the AppStore.

**1) Subclass UITabBarItem**

Create a subclass of UITabBarItem and add a new `selected` property to its header, like so:

```
@interface ALDTabBarItem : UITabBarItem
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isSelected) BOOL selected;
@end
```

UITabBarItems have a view property, but it isn't exposed. We can extend the class to access it, and then create a custom setter on the `selected` property to change the background colour, like so:

```
#import "ALDTabBarItem.h"

@interface ALDTabBarItem (ALD)
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@end

@implementation ALDTabBarItem

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if(selected)
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
} 

@end
```

**2) Update your UITabBarController delegate**

Add the following code to the delegate of your UITabBarController, which sets the selected states of the UITabBar:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    for(ALDTabBarItem *myItem in tabBar.items)
        myItem.selected = (myItem == item);
}
```

Comment: Please, edit variable's name at the very end of Your code `myItem.selected = (myitem == item);` => `myItem.selected = (myItem == item);`  (myItem). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

In Swift

```
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "tabSelected")
```

with an image `tabSelected@2x.png` of size 98x98 pixels

Comment: Now this is the freakin easiest way to change the background color of yout tabbarItem when it is selected. Please don't be stubborn guys. :D Subclassing the TabbarItem no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

Follow this Steps:

1. Create SubClass of `UITabBarController`
2. Go to `viewDidAppear` of `UITabBarController` subclass
3. Now Find the size of TabBarItem,

   ```
   UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
   CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.size.width/tabBar.items.count,tabBar.frame.size.height);
   ```
4. Now Create the image with that size,

   ```
   //Create Image
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, NO, 0);
   UIBezierPath* p =
   [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
   [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
   [p fill];
   UIImage* finalImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```
5. Now, Assign this image to TabBar's `SelectionIndicatorImage`

   ```
   [tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:finalImg];
   ```

**Swift 4 Version:**

```
let imgSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.size.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count),
                     height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, false, 0)
let p = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgSize.width,
                                  height: imgSize.height))
UIColor.blue.setFill()
p.fill()
let finalImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = finalImg
```

Answer (score 5):

My answer is similar to **@Mehul Thakkar** but it is in **Swift 4** and to improve on his answer I would say that if you place the code in `viewDidAppear` as he suggests users will see the change happening which is not good user experience.

So create the custom class for your tabbar controller and in `viewDidLoad`
place the following code:

```
let singleTabWidth: CGFloat = self.tabBar.frame.size.width / CGFloat((self.tabBar.items?.count)!)
let singleTabSize = CGSize(width:singleTabWidth , height: self.tabBar.frame.size.height)

let selectedTabBackgroundImage: UIImage = self.imageWithColor(color: .white, size: singleTabSize)
self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = selectedTabBackgroundImage
```

The `imageWithColor` function is below for you:

```
//image with color and size
    func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your answer is 100 % correct, but the reason behind putting the code in viewDidAppear is we get final actual width of screen. If your code is in viewDidLoad, then you will be seeing the issues with different sized screens.(works for only specific screen sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below URL's.

[Changing Tint / Background color of UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar)

[How To Change Tab bar color in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310651/how-to-change-tab-bar-color-in-xcode)

hope this will help you..

try this to change tabbar item color but it only work in ios5.

```
if ([UITabBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setSelectedImageTintColor:)])
{
    [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: i edit my Q. plz chk. or you can follow this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799572/how-to-change-tabbar-icon-color-from-default-blue"..

Answer (score 0):

You can use tintcolor.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In AppDelegate.m, put the following code after // Override point for customization after application launch.

Comment: This changes only the color of title. what If we want to change the color of complete box .i.e tab bar item.

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your AppDelegate.m file:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.

            [UITabBar appearance].selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"activeTabBackgroundImage"];


            return YES;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Xcode 8.3.2 you can do it inside the storyboard using an image that will represent the actual background.

Select the tab bar inside your tab bar controller:

[image]

Inside the Utilities choose the Attributes Inspector and change the selection background image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer in swift 4:

**setSelectedImageTintColor is deprecated on iOS 8.**

Instead use this :

**self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white**